# pde equation complex plane

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following differential equation:

```
DSolve[{D[χ[β, βc, t],t] == -Γ (β D[χ[β, βc,t], β] + βc D[χ[β, βc, t], βc])}, χ, {β, βc, t}]
```

and this is the output

```
{* {χ -> Function[{β, βc, t}, C[1][βc/β, (t Γ - Log[β])/Γ]]} *}
```

Now:

1. I don't understand why the result is written as a function of two arguments
2. What is the meaning of `(t Γ - Log[β])/Γ`?

Comment: First, the solution is not a function of two arguments but of three `{\[Beta], \[Beta]c, t}`. Your solution is given in the form of `PureFunction`. For details about pure function see this [link](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PureFunctions.html). Regarding last part of your question, `t[CapitalGamma]-Log[[Beta]])/[CapitalGamma]` is part of the solution (again see link for pure function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
eqn = D[χ[β, βc, t], 
    t] == -Γ (β D[χ[β, βc, 
         t], β] + βc D[χ[β, βc, t], βc]);

soln = DSolve[eqn, χ, {β, βc, t}][[1]]

{χ -> Function[{β, βc, t}, 
   C[1][βc/β, (t Γ - Log[β])/Γ]]}
```

Verifying the solution

```
eqn /. soln // Simplify

(*  True  *)
```

`C[1]` is an arbitrary `function` of its two shown parameters. For example. let `C[1]` be the undefined function `f`

```
soln2 = soln /. C[1] -> f

(*  {χ -> Function[{β, βc, t}, 
   f[βc/β, (t Γ - Log[β])/Γ]]}  *)
```

As expected, this solution also satisfies the equation

```
eqn /. soln2 // Simplify

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: I tried to impose χ[β, βc, 0]==E^(-(β βc)/2 but i didn't get anything

Comment: @Kowalski - your condition appears to be inconsistent with the general solution. `\[Chi][\[Beta], \[Beta]c, 0]` must be expressible as a function of the arguments `{\[Beta]c / \[Beta],  -Log[\[Beta]] / \[CapitalGamma]}`

Comment: But I found that also \[Chi] -> Function[{β, βc, t}, C[1][β E^(-Γt), βc E^(-Γt)]], is a solution, so my condition is not inconsistent, i'm right?

Comment: @Kowalski - I'm not a mathematician and I don't know how to force Mathematica to provide a result using your constraint.